# How to make a generic type constraint instanciable

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript-generics

I have these two code fragments how can I change them so that MemberModel can be passed in as generic type and remains instanciatable so that I can extract the follow method into its own exported function?

```
export interface IFollowable {
    follow(user: IUserModel): IMemberModel;
}

export class CardModel implements ICardModel, IFollowable {
    public follow(user: IUserModel): IMemberModel {
        let member = new MemberModel({userId: user.id});
        member.role = UserRoles.follower;
        this.members.push(member);
        return member;
    }
}
```

How do I make follow and IFollowable generic so that the whatever type I pass in remains newable like the MemberModel is right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so that the whatever type I pass in remains newable like the MemberModel is right now

Because typescript generics are erased at compile time you need to pass them in explicitly e.g. using a factory as shown below:

```
type User = {name:string};
type Member = {name: string};
type MemberCreator = {new (user:User): Member};

interface Followable {
    follow(user: User, memberCreator: MemberCreator): Member;
}

export class CardModel implements Followable {
    public follow(user: User, memberCreator: MemberCreator): Member {
       return new memberCreator(user);
    }
}
```